# Choose one variable from many in T-SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, reporting-services

I have a problem with T-SQL statements for SSRS. In my report I have 2 variables, which only one can be chosen by user. I have to write an query which depends on user choice. I'll try to give you an example:

```
@varA = 'sometext'
@varB = 'othertext'

SELECT A.SomeValue, B.SomeValue
FROM tableA AS A
INNER JOIN tableB AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE 
   (and here comes my problem)
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem? Does variable must be compared to the same value or both variables compared to different values? Can variables be `NULL` if user doesn't select them?

Comment: try to use case condition in select statement only why to use in where condition if @varA come B.somevalue will be null and viceversa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT A.SomeValue, B.SomeValue
FROM tableA AS A
INNER JOIN tableB AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE (sometext_col = @varA  or @varA is null) 
And   (othertext_col = @varB  or @varB is null)
```

This query will return rows based on the user selection.

- If user selects only `@varA` then data will be filtered based on
  `@varA`
- If user selects only `@varB` then data will be filtered based on
  `@varB`
- If user selects both `@varA` and `@varB` then data be filtered on
  both the variables.
- If user doesn't selects anything then all the rows will be returned
  from the table.

**Note :** When user doesn't selects a variable then make sure it is `NULL`

Comment: I'll check this tommorow in the office, but it looks legit. Thx vm Fireblade